# MacPython: programmatically finding all serial ports

Tags: python, macos, serial-port

I am looking for a solution to programmatically return all available serial ports with python.

At the moment I am entering `ls /dev/tty.*` or `ls /dev/cu.*` into the terminal to list ports and hardcoding them into the pyserial class.

Answer (score 6):

You could do something like this:

```
import glob
def scan():
    return glob.glob('/dev/tty*') + glob.glob('/dev/cu*')

for port in scan():
   # do something to check this port is open.
```

Then, take a look at [pyserial](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/) for some good utility functions to check if a port is open and so forth.

Comment: pySerial docs on using it to enumerate serial ports: http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/examples.html#finding-serial-ports

Answer (score 1):

What about just doing the `os.listdir` / `glob` equivalent of `ls` to perform the equivalent of that `ls`?  Of course it's not going to be the case that some usable device is connected to each such special file (but, that holds for `ls` as well;-), but for "finding *all* serial ports", as you ask in your Q's title, I'm not sure how *else* you might proceed.